# Proof that an event can't happen infinitely often

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent binary events such that $P(X_n=1)=1-P(X_n=0)=2^{-n}$. My task is to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$ converges almost surely. Here is my work:

To show that the sum converges almost surely, by Borel-Cantelli, it suffices to show  that $P[X_n=1$ infinitely often $]=0$.

First, note that there are countably many subsequences $(n_i)$ of the natural numbers. Next, note that for some particular subsequence $(n_i^*)$, the following holds:

$P(X_{n_i^*}=1$ for all $n_i^*)\leq P(X_n=1$ for all $n)=0$ because $P(X_n=1)$ is decreasing in $n$. Hence, we have that $P(X_{n_i^*}=1$ infinitely often $)=0$ for any particular subsequence of the natural numbers, and since there are countably many, $P(X_{n_i}=1$ infinitely often for at least one subsequence $(n_i)$)=0$.

Therefore, $P[X_n=1$ infinitely often $]=0$, i.e. the sum converges almost surely.

Comment: Why do you say there are countably many subsequences of the natural numbers?

Comment: @kimchilover because if the probability of an event is 0 and there are countably many such events, then the probability of at least one of these events is also 0.

Comment: @Roberto That's the obvious motivation, but you need a justification too. Otherwise any theorem could be "proved" by deriving it from a false statement (like yours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is wrong. It is not true that there are only countably many subsequences of natural numbers.

$\sum P(X_n=1)=\sum \frac 1 {2^{n}} <\infty$. Borel -Cantelli Lemma tells you that $P(X_n=1 \text {infinitley often}) =0$ or $P(X_n=0 \, \text {for all sufficiently large } n) =1$ so the series converges almost surely.

Comment: Why do you take the sum instead of the product?

Comment: I am only using the easy part of Borel Cantelly. Independence is not required at all here.

Comment: Ok But I don't understand why you're adding the probabilities?

Comment: @Roberto The condition of the lemma is that $\sum P(E_n) < \infty.$ Why would you _not_ add the probabilities?

Comment: @DavidK I had actually miswritten the lemma...